# How do you see the contents of Cookies in Use on Android Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies, cookie-session

Ive been searching for the past 2 hours and all the results are just blocking and clearing cookies and I DONT want that.
I want to view the contents of Cookies like this image here but on Android
[website folder with cookies and it's content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAPmI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view the cookies being saved by your mobile's chrome, you can just use  [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/),  which allows you to inspect the pages open on your phone, but the dev tools windows themselves have to be viewed on PC.

If you're not interested in remote, I've heard good things about [Eruda](https://dev.to/asaoluelijah/how-to-access-dev-tool-on-mobile-browsers-14nd), which makes it possible to access dev tools on you mobile device.